# Where to store secret token in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, security, github, token

So I have created a programs the first one is the main app and the the second one is the admin app.

The admin app is to customize the main app and set it up.
The app uses github as storage, because it's secure and free.
So in the admin app, you enter your github personal access token, so the main app has access to the repo (the storage).

The main app is for other user, so basically if the setup is finish, you can share the main app and all config files. (the final program)

The admin (the person that customized the main app) shares the main app e.g. on his/her website, so the personal access token needs to be in the files that get shared.

A personal access token is for the GithubAPI or octokit API to get data from private or public repo's you don't own. (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Now the question is here, how to save the personal access token?
Locally in a config file or in a database and then is the question how to save the database password and user?

Comment: Store your local user settings in a file below `%AppData%\Toolname\settings.xxx`. The app data folder is below the user folder, where only the logged in user has access.

Comment: I think you didn't understand correctly. The admin app is for the admin it doesn't get shared, the main app is for OTHER user's so the admin shares e.g. on his/her website so other people can download it. To store the personal access token into the user settings makes no sense. How can other user's have access to the user settings from the admin???

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule is that you should never store any secrets in client applications that are downloaded by end users. You should always assume that the code can be reverse engineered.

To authenticate or authorize a request, you could for example store a one-way hash of the password or token in a database. Then let the user supply a token, send it to the server, hash it and compare the output of the hash with the stored value.

Comment: Yes, but the github personal access token is a token or password that the end user don't know, so the request can't be authorized by a end user.

Comment: So then you need to map it with a credential that the end-user does know. This is how it works on GitHub. You sign in to get a token.

Comment: The end user don't need to sign, because with the octokit api you can get all data I need with the personal token from the admin. Still server doesn't know about the token that the user created.

Comment: Your question doesn't mentione anything about some "octokit api". And how is the user supposed to not sign in but still get a token...?

Comment: Either way, "the personal access token needs to be in the files that get shared" is wrong. You don't share secrets in files that are distributed one way or another.

Comment: Only personal access tokens (classic) have write access for public or private repositories that are not owned by you or an organization that you are not a member of. (that is a persona access token. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: I think you don't know what a personal access token is. It can be only used in GithubApi in the restapi or in the octokit api.

Comment: Yes, I know what a token is. But you ask where to store it in your app, don't you? And I say that you don't store personal tokens in files that you distribute. What's left to the question....?

Comment: The question is still open, you said to not store it in a file, but it's still no solution.

Comment: Store it in the server side is the solution. How you retrieve and use it depends on how you authorize a user in your application. If you don't implement some kind of authorization, using personal tokens is totally useless.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your help, but it's sadly not possible to authorize it and a local storage isn't that great either.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the database but I'd recommend the applications config file for a few reasons.  One of which is for deployments down the road where you can setup CI/CD to fill in the values for you by environment.  If you want to encrypt the section in your config for some added safety there are a few ways.  Here is one of them:

```
//Change to your Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version directory
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.serviceModel/bindings" 
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.serviceModel/services"
```

If security is extremely important you may consider storing it in protected memory in case the memory dump but that's a step above.